# GPU rendering error

Tags: rendering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lhxY.jpg)
Hi,
How do i start GPU compute while Rendering.
i am using AMD READON GRAPHICS CARD R9 360 BUT BLENDER 2.79v is not reading my graphics card.
PLEASE hELP

[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong about this AMD cards are not supported yet ... it's a bummer I know. Go nvidia! ... the manual says this ... Cycles has two GPU rendering modes: CUDA, which is the preferred method for Nvidia graphics cards; and OpenCL, which supports rendering on AMD graphics cards. You can try to see if switching to OpenCL helps

Comment: ... more on this on the page "OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. (We only support graphics cards with GCN architecture 2.0 and above). To make sure your GPU is supported checkout" So do check if your card is GCN architecture 2.0 read here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html